# Why is my Monte Carlo Raytracing so noisy?

Tags: render, intersection, raytracing, noise, light

I have implemented global illumination using the Monte Carlo method, using the scratch a pixel tutorial as a guide. My final image renders very noisy! The example below is at 64 samples, I have previously used as high as 512 and its still very noisy.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

[image: 64 Samples, 1 Bounce]

Edit:
Here is the output with 128 samples and 16x Super sampling,resulting in 2048 samples. Still lots of noise!

[image]

Comment: That's just how it is.  Mine works much the same.

Comment: Are you sure it supposed to be this bad? I have tried to combat the noise by using 16x supersampling (grid algorithm) and 128 samples but its still bad!

Comment: Mine needs a few thousand samples to get acceptable noise levels.  FWIW, I don't use a grid for supersampling - I just pick floating point x and y samples and then just add those into the right pixel bucket for those ray coordinates.

Comment: p.s. http://raybellis.github.io/RRT/

Comment: Just uploaded a new image with 2048 samples, still lots of noise on the floor. I know its supposed to be noisy but surely not this much? Could it be to do with the fact that rays that exit the box contribute a sample of 0?

Comment: The rays exiting the box certainly won't help - putting a large sphere around the world can help a lot, although it will of course also affect the overall illumination inside the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Path tracing is pretty noisy; it's the nature of the algorithm. Consider this example from Wikipedia:

[image]

The top left image is at 1 sample per pixel, and from there (left to right, top to bottom), each following square doubles that. So the bottom right square is at 32768 spp.

There are other, related algorithms that can reduce noise for the same amount of computation:

- [Bidirectional path tracing](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348b-03/papers/veach-chapter10.pdf)
- [Photon mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_mapping)