# how to prevent grey noise when using render_highquality() in rayshader

Tags: r, 3d, rayshader

I need to output a high res image using `render_highquality` using `plot_gg()` of the rayshader/rayrender package. However, I always seem to get a strange grey noise filter over my image, how can I prevent this from happening? (this does not happen if I just use `render_snapshot()`

So this works (from the package examples):

```
library(rayshader)
library(rayrender)

volcano %>%
  sphere_shade() %>%
  plot_3d(volcano,zscale = 2)
render_snapshot(clear = TRUE,filename="p1_snap.png")
```

[image]

But this yields an unexpected result.

```
volcano %>%
  sphere_shade() %>%
  plot_3d(volcano,zscale = 2)
render_highquality(clear = TRUE, filename="p1_hq.png")
```

[image]

I just want the background to be white

Comment: I don't know about this package but try playing around with the lighting parameters in the `render_highquality` function. For example, adding `lightsize = 50` as a parameter allowed me to get rid mostly of the dim/grey background that you see in the second picture.

Comment: As it seems to me, `render_highquality` implements a _path-tracing_ renderer, which chooses the placement, direction, and scatter of rays pseudorandomly.  In exchange, the rendering will take into account shadows, light occlusion, and global illumination very accurately.  With a finite sample size, though, the image generated by any such renderer will inevitably have noise.  And to reduce that noise, either a larger sample size or a specially-designed _denoiser_ is needed.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449353/why-is-my-monte-carlo-raytracing-so-noisy

Comment: Thank you both. This does unfortunately does not really solve my problem, but I will try rerunning with a lot more samples.

Comment: @LSmeets Did you ever manage to figure this out? I am searching now for a solution...